# Configurar SQL Server en ubuntu 20.04 para revertir cambio a horario de verano

Tags: sql-server, ubuntu

Tengo un servidor con ubuntu 20.04 y en el está instalado el SQL Server 2019.

Este año se cambió la ley en México para quitar el cambio al horario de verano, por lo cual no se debería actualizar el reloj del servidor.

El servidor efectivamente no cambió la hora, pero, el SQL Server, al hacer un GETDATE() muestra la hora como si hubiera cambiado el horario.

Estuve investigando y veo que la tabla time_zone_info es donde está el problema, porque marca que si cambió.

```
select *
from sys.time_zone_info
where name like '%mexico%'
```

¿Conocerán alguna forma para poder actualizar esa tabla?

Lo que hice como workarround fue cambiar la zona horaria del servidor a una fronteriza para que simulara que no cambió el horario y eso me arreglo el problema, pero, no creo que sea una solución correcta.

esto es lo que me regresa el sever en linux

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

mientras que esto es lo que me regresa un server con sql en windows

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1):

Necesitas actualizar la información de zonas horarias a nivel del sistema operativo.

Para ello puedes valerte del comando [`zic`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/man8/zic.8.html), que es el *timezone compiler*.
Lo siguiente que necesitas son los datos de las zonas horarias actualizadas, conocidos en general como `tzdata` (de *time zone data*).

Puedes obtener datos actualizados de la [base de datos de zonas horarias de la IANA](https://www.iana.org/time-zones), por ejemplo el [release 2023c](https://data.iana.org/time-zones/releases/tzdata2023c.tar.gz) que es el último a la fecha de la publicación de esta respuesta. Puedes ver todos los releases en [la carpeta de releases](https://data.iana.org/time-zones/).

Los comandos para actualizar toda la base de datos al release 2023c en tu caja local serían:

```bsh
wget https://data.iana.org/time-zones/releases/tzdata2023c.tar.gz
tar xvzf tzdata2023c.tar.gz
sudo zic africa
sudo zic antarctica
sudo zic asia
sudo zic australasia
sudo zic europe
sudo zic northamerica
sudo zic southamerica
```

Después de un reinicio del servicio, el SQL Server debiera funcionar correctamente.

Comment: gracias por tu respuesta,
ya lo realicé y sigue igual, incluso reinicié el server
tendrás alguna otra idea?

Comment: ¿Podrías editar la pregunta y mostrar qué te está devolviendo la consulta a `sys.time_zone_info`?

Comment: listo, ya las agregué

Comment: Diría que `zic` no está teniendo efecto. Si ejecutas en una terminal: `TZ=America/Mexico_City date -R`, te devuelve la hora correcta?

Comment: ¿y `TZ=UTC date -R`?

Comment: Si la hora en el servidor es la hora correcta, ahí si "respetó" el ca echo de que no haya cambio de horario. el detalle está focalizado solamente en el sql server.

Comment: Hasta donde entiendo SQL Server interroga al sistema operativo en estos casos, es decir, delega la tarea en el sistema base, por decirlo de alguna manera. ¿Qué tal una llamada al soporte de Microsoft?

Comment: Si, esa sería mi siguiente parada, solo que, quería ver si a alguien del foro le había pasado, de igual manera, muchas gracias por el apoyo